# Post: Bind Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my Database I have Members Table and Pictures tables. A Member can have 1 to many Pictures. When Post has been made the member.Picture.Count = 0, I can't understand Why? and How should I solve this?

What Iam doing is:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        Member member = new Member();
        Picture pic = new Picture();
        member.Pictures.add();

        return View(new ClassifiedsFormViewModel(member));
    }
```

//POST:

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create(Member member)
        {

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                classifiedsRepository.Add(member);
                classifiedsRepository.Save();

                return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = member.MemberId });
            }
            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddModelErrors(member.GetRuleViolations());
            }
        }

        return View(new ClassifiedsFormViewModel(member));
    }
```

Comment: Do you have some kid of input control on your form for the picture? And why are you doing a redirect to Create and passing an id when your Create method doesn't have an id parameter?

Comment: yes I have a control for my picture. The problem is that the Picture dosen't get saved. When setting the debugg inside the POST: create action then Member.Pictures.Count = 0... 

Can this be because Iam using Linq to SQL

Answer (score 0):

From what code you have provided the only thing I can see is where you're calling `member.Pictures.add` you're not actually passing anything in.  Therefor nothing is getting added to the pictures collection.